# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}' at character 2

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

I am currently working on a cookie clicker with an own custom console. It just should be a cookie clicker clone. A shop or anything else I haven't added yet.
The problem is, when you run the code there's an error called

```
expected expression, got '}' [More Information] index.html:2
```

(exactly copied from firefox)
The weird thing is that the gotten '}' is at the second used character, which is in the  tag.
How can it get an '}' in the  tag?

The code looks like this:

```js
//init
var clicks = 0;
var button = document.getElementById("clickme");
var consoleMsgs = 0;
var myConsole = document.getElementById('console');
consoleLog("Button clicker initiated!");

function buttonClick() {
  clicks++;
  consoleLog('You have ' + clicks + ' clicks!');
  button.value = 'Clicks: ' + clicks;
}

function consoleLog(t) {
  consoleMsgs++
  myConsole.children[1].innerHTML = '<p style="margin-bottom: 0;" id=' + consoleMsgs + '>' + t + '</p>' + myConsole.children[1].innerHTML;
}
```

```css
input {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: thick;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  background: #232328;
  margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
  color: #d3dde6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Romgl</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap Dependencies -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="content" style="font-size: 1.5rem; margin: 0.7ex">
    <div>
      <input id="clickme" value="Clicks: 0" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 100px;" onclick="buttonClick();" type="submit">

      <input value="clear console" style="margin-right: 10px;" onclick="myConsole.children[1].innerHTML = " ";=" " consolemsgs="0; " consolelog('console=" " cleared!');"="" type="submit">

      <div id="console" style="font-size: 1.3rem;">
        <h1>Console</h1>
        <div class="consoleText">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Please help me!

Comment: see this `onclick="myConsole.children[1].innerHTML = " ";=" " consolemsgs="0; " consolelog('console=" " cleared!');"=""` ... that's complete rubbish

Comment: it could be `onclick="myConsole.children[1].innerHTML=''; consoleMsgs=0; consoleLog('cleared!');"` and then it works, however, using `onclick` attribute is best left to 20 year old code

Comment: @JaromandaX I want to know if do not use `onclick` attribute,what shall we use now,thank you

Comment: well, if you want to use onclick, use it better .. dont' put multiple statements, call a function ... like you do in the other onclick!!! ... but, look at element `addEventListener` method for better code

Answer (score 0):

You **really** should avoid putting JS in your HTML inputs.

You could do something along these lines :

```js
//init
var clicks = 0;
var button = document.getElementById("clickme");
var consoleMsgs = 0;
var myConsole = document.getElementById('console');
consoleLog("Button clicker initiated!");

document.getElementById("clickme").addEventListener('click', function() {
  clicks++;
  consoleLog('You have ' + clicks + ' clicks!');
  button.value = 'Clicks: ' + clicks;
});

document.getElementById("clicktoclear").addEventListener('click', function(){
  myConsole.children[1].innerHTML='';
  consoleMsgs=0;
  consoleLog('cleared!');
});

function consoleLog(t) {
  consoleMsgs++
  myConsole.children[1].innerHTML = '<p style="margin-bottom: 0;" id=' + consoleMsgs + '>' + t + '</p>' + myConsole.children[1].innerHTML;
}
```

```css
input {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: thick;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  background: #232328;
  margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
  color: #d3dde6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Romgl</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Dependencies -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="content" style="font-size: 1.5rem; margin: 0.7ex">
      <div>
        <input id="clickme" value="Clicks: 0" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 100px;"  type="submit">

        <input id="clicktoclear" value="clear console" style="margin-right: 10px;" type="submit">

        <div id="console" style="font-size: 1.3rem;">
          <h1>Console</h1>
          <div class="consoleText">
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Remove the extra </div> -->

  </body>

</html>
```

I just moved the JS you had in your input to the actual JS script and corrected your code to clear your console.
Also, you had an extra  in your HTML that I removed.

EDIT : I just removed the jQuery to switch to pure JS to match the original code.

Comment: Thanks, but the real problem was in the onclick:
     `onclick="myConsole.children[1].innerHTML = " ";=" " consolemsgs="0; " consolelog('console=" " cleared!');"="" `
but I'm gonna remember that!

Comment: @Darxoon Yeah I know, but since Jaromanda X corrected your error in the comments, I was elaborating on your follow up question that was how to avoid using `onclick` ;)